# Backbone access a View from model in another Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am learning Backbone and loving it. At the moment I am stuck in a problem I am not sure how to solve.

I have two collections of Items:

1. in an Items List
2. in a Shopping List

Each Model from each Collection is linked as they are the same product, but I create a new Model for each Collection to handle it separately. So when I remove an item from the Shopping List it does not remove it from the Items List.

The problem appears when I add an element from the Items List to the Shopping list. At this point, I change the color of the wrapper to visually indicate that it has been added. But then when I remove it from the Shopping List I do not know how to access the View in the Item List as the Model in the Shopping List is a new one from the same product.

[This test link](http://www.elinfante.net/freelance/backbone/) will help you understand.

Can you advise on how to access, or link a View from a Model?

Comment: you will need a [mediator pattern](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/03/18/event-aggregator-andorvs-mediator-a-tale-of-two-patterns/). As a note, [MarionetteJS](http://marionettejs.com/) will help organizing your app. It extends Backbone to have common pattern and method already done for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a brand new model for the shopping list collection you could share the same model and use an additional attribute to figure out if it's inside the shopping list. Depending on the structure of your program you could have the shopping list collection listen to the item collection to see if any models have had their `added` attribute modified, if they have then they're added to the shopping list collection. Once an item is removed from the shopping list collection then the `added` attribute is updated to reflect that which would allow you to remove the highlight color.